# Calculate by cell statistics of Image Collection in (R) Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, r, google-earth-engine, ndvi, cell-statistics

I am using Google Earth Engine in R via the `rgee` package. My goal is to calculate median NDVI for each cell in an image collection. I have an image collection gathered via:

```
#This is not a reprex
addNDVI <- function(image) {
  ndvi <- image$normalizedDifference(c('B5', 'B4'))$rename('NDVI');
  return(image$addBands(ndvi))
}

collection <- ee$ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')$
  filterDate('2014-01-01', '2019-12-31')$
  filterBounds(region)$
  map(addNDVI)$
  select('NDVI')
```

but adding `$median()` to the end of the `ee$ImageCollection()` call calculates the total median of all cells in all images, returning only one number. I am looking to calculate the individual by-cell median, similar to what is done below using `raster::calc()`:

```r
#This is a reprex
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
set.seed(1)
t1=raster(matrix(data=rnorm(9,mean=10,sd=2),nrow=3,ncol=3))
t2=raster(matrix(data=rnorm(9,mean=10,sd=2),nrow=3,ncol=3))
t3=raster(matrix(data=rnorm(9,mean=10,sd=2),nrow=3,ncol=3))

par(mfrow=c(1,4))
plot(t1,main='t1 data')
plot(t2,main='t2 data')
plot(t3,main='t3 data')
t3 = brick(t1,t2,t3)
t4 = raster::calc(t3,fun=median)
plot(t4,main="median of t1 - t3")
```

[image]